# How to add a search function to my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a music player using JavaScript and I am trying to add a search bar to my page but every tutorial I have seen so far uses a list created in the HTML page, whereas I have created a list using JavaScript code like this:

```
const songs = [
    "BlindingLights.mp3",
    "Boyfriend.mp3",
    "DontStartNow.mp3",
    "Intentions.mp3",
    "Physical"
]

const createSongList = () => {
    const list = document.createElement('ol')

    for(let i = 0; i<songs.length; i++){
        const item = document.createElement('li')
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(songs[i]))

        list.appendChild(item)
    }

    return list
}

document.getElementById('songList').appendChild(createSongList())
```

Is there a way I can use the 'songs' array or to develop a search function? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Edit for clarity:

So I have an input tag on my html that I want to use for a search bar, then I want what the user types in to return any matching songs from the songs array. For example if they type in 'Bli' I want it to show the Blinding Lights song. 
The code snippet above is how I am currently displaying a list of songs using the array.

This is my input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="searchBar()">
```

Comment: 1 - How do you want to use the songs array ? 2-where Will you use it on your page ? If you can upload the page to us as a code snippet and specify here that you would like to use it in this way, it will be more descriptive.

Comment: I edited my post to hopefully be a bit more clear :)

Comment: add onChange listener on input box and send whatever is inside the input to search function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to filter `songs` array from a search string, you can use this function :

```js
const songs = [
    "BlindingLights.mp3",
    "Boyfriend.mp3",
    "DontStartNow.mp3",
    "Intentions.mp3",
    "Physical"
];

const searchSong = (value) => {
  return songs.filter(song => song.includes(value));
};

console.log(searchSong('B'));
```

Comment: I think what he wants is to reconstruct the search structure and filter this search list according to the searches. It shouldn't be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a new function `search` to Array.prototype to make it used more easily

```
Array.prototype.search = function (keyword) {
  return this.filter(text => text.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase().trim()))
}  
const songs = [
    "BlindingLights.mp3",
    "Boyfriend.mp6",
    "DontStartNow.mp5",
    "Intentions.mp3",
    "Physical"
];

songs.search('phy ')  // => ["Physical"]
songs.search(' MP3')  // =>  ["BlindingLights.mp3", "Intentions.mp3"]
```